# Where sitecore keeps languages found in SC.Context.Database.Languages?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore7, sitecore8

I have following code:

```
public void Process(SC.Pipelines.HttpRequest.HttpRequestArgs args)
{
   if (HttpContext.Current == null || SC.Context.Database == null)
   {
      return;
   }
string languageCode = DomainHandler.Instance.GetDomainLanguage(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host);
SC.Globalization.Language language = SC.Context.Database.Languages.First(x => x.Name == languageCode);
```

that results in error message once run:

```
Sequence contains no matching element
```

I'm guessing somebody deleted the languages and now  SC.Context.Database.Languages collection is empty hence the error.

I can not log into sitecore cms and I'm curious how I can fix this?

Comment: Languages collection is not empty. Languages collection does not contain a language with `name` equal to your `languageCode`. Check what is your language code. And check what languages are on your list.

Answer (score 1):

You should get the current language just by saying

```
var languages = Context.Database.GetLanguages();
```

Then you can apply the Where clause. There may be a difference between Db.Languages and Db.GetLanguages()

Comment: thanks, but I'm curious why languages collection is empty? This only occur on production server but not on my development machine ...

Comment: Did you publish the language content items from master to web?

Comment: If you have languages in Master db and you do not have them in Web db then they are not published. If you publish them and they still are not there then there is something wrong with your publishing. Check your Log files. Check publishing restrictions on the languages or even up to the root level... you never know.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't solved the problem but curbed it so that user can at least log into cms by assigning default language in case none of them is available by using following code:

```
string languageCode = DomainHandler.Instance.GetDomainLanguage(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host);
var languages = SC.Context.Database.GetLanguages().Where(l => l.Name == languageCode);
//make dutch default language
SC.Globalization.Language language = Sitecore.Globalization.Language.Parse("nl-NL");
if (languages.Count() > 0)
{
    language = languages.First();
}
```

I'm still puzzled why languages collections is empty?

Answer (score 0):

sitecore languages are stored in /sitecore/system/languages node.
Also, it is always good to use FirstOrDefault instead of First, since First will return an exception if matching item was not found.

Answer (score 0):

May be little late..  But can you try this

```
Sitecore.Collections.LanguageCollection languages = LanguageManager.GetLanguages(Sitecore.Context.ContentDatabase);
string languageCode = "xxx"; //get some logic to get your language code. 
Sitecore.Globalization.Language language = languages.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == languageCode);
```